# Automorphism of principal bundles and sections of the adjoint bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, schemes, principal-bundles

I am studying the paper of Biswas and Ramanan *An infinitesimal study of the moduli space of hitching pairs* and at some point they make a statement that I don't know if it is true because they don't give any kind of reference. The authors consider a smooth projective curve $C$ over $\mathbb{C}$, and algebraic group $G$. Let $P$ be a principal $G$ bundle over $C$ and let $P(\epsilon):=P\times\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[\epsilon])$ where $\epsilon^2=0$ the $G$-bundle over $C\times\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[\epsilon])$ obtained by the pullback through the projection $C\times\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[\epsilon])\rightarrow C$ on the first factor. They claim that is equivalent to give an automorphism of $P(\epsilon)$ which induces the identity over the closed point that to give a section of the adjoint bundle $ad P$ (the fibers are the lie algebra of $G$). For a section $s$ of $ad P$, the corresponding automorphism is denoted by $1+\epsilon s$.  Can anybody explain to me why this is true or at least give some reference for this (a priori, well-known) fact?

Comment: Include a definition of the adjoint bundle $ad(P)$. If $P$ is a rank $n$ locally trivial $\mathcal{O}_X$-module (a finite rank vector bundle or a $GL_n$-bundle?) - what is $ad(P)$?

Comment: The adjoint bundle is $(P\times \mathfrak{g})/G$ where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ and $G$ acts on $\mathfrak{g}$ through the adjoint representation. In the case that $P$ is a rank $n$ vector bundle $ad P$ is $End(P)$, isn't it?

Comment: If $E$ is a rank $n$ locally trivial $\mathcal{O}_X$-module it follows $F:=End_{\mathcal{O}_X}(E) \cong E \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}E^*$ is  locally trivial of rank $n^2$, and $F$ has canonically the structure of a Lie algebra. If $U:=Spec(A)$ is an open affine subscheme where $E(U) \cong M$, $M$ a projective $A$-module, it follows $F(U) \cong M \otimes_A M^*$ and $F(U)$ is canonically an $A$-Lie algebra.

Comment: Hence $F$ is a sheaf of locally trivial finite rank $\mathcal{O}_X$-Lie algebras. You speak of quotients - how do they use quotients in the above mentioned paper?

Comment: When they talk about quotients they are referring to the usual construction of the associated fiber bundle, that is a scheme over $C$ with typical fiber $\mathfrak{g}$. Sorry  @hm2020, but I don't see how your answer relates to my original question.

Comment: You get for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq A$ the formula $M^*\otimes_A M \otimes_A A/\mathfrak{m} \cong (M\otimes_A A/\mathfrak{m})^*\otimes_A (M\otimes_A A/\mathfrak{m}) \cong GL_{\kappa(\mathfrak{m})}(M(\mathfrak{m}))$ hence the fiber of $F$ at $\mathfrak{m}$ is a $\kappa(\mathfrak{m})$-Lie algebra.

Comment: Im trying to understand your question in terms of locally trivial sheaves (principal $GL_n$-bundles). In the affine stuation there is a canonical extension $A \rightarrow A[\epsilon]$ and $E \rightarrow E[\epsilon]$ and it seems you want an equivalence between a certain set of automorphisms of $E[\epsilon]$ and global sections of $F:=ad(E)$, that is endomorphisms $End_A(M)$.

Comment: The bundle $M[\epsilon]\cong M\oplus M\epsilon$ is a direct sum, and an endomorphism $\phi$ of this bundle inducing the identity must be on the form $\phi(e+f\epsilon)= e+s(f)\epsilon$. where $s\in End_A(M)$. It may be this is related to your question for principal $GL_n$-bundles. If you want an automorphism you should choose $$ to be an automorphism.

Comment: Well, that makes sense, so if we want that the automorphism $\phi$ induces the identity when $\epsilon=0$, then $\phi=1+\epsilon s$ with $s\in End_A(M)$.

Comment: The point is that $Aut_A(M) \subsetneq End_A(M)$ is a strict subgroup. If you want automorphisms you may have to choose an $s\in Aut_A(M)$.

Comment: So... since $C$ is a curve every principal bundle is locally trivial with respect the Zariskit topology. Let $\{U_{i}\}$ a covering of $C$ by affine open sets. Then $\{U_{i}\times Spec(\mathbb{C}[\epsilon])\}$ is an affine open covering of $C[\epsilon]$ where $P[\epsilon]$ is trivial on each $U{i}[\epsilon]$, so we have that for each $i$, $P_{i}$ is of the form $Spec(A_{i}\otimes \mathbb{C][G]\otimes \mathbb{C}[\epsilon}])$

Comment: If $\phi:=1+s\epsilon, \psi:=1+t\epsilon$ with $s,t\in End_A(M)$, it follows the "obvious" composition is $\phi\circ \psi:=1+ (s \circ t) \epsilon$. And this is not an automorphism in general. If $s,t$ have non-trivial kernel it follows the maps $\phi, \psi$ are non-automorphisms.

Comment: Therefore, an automorphism of $P_{\epsilon}$ will be equivalent to give an  automorphism of $A_{i}\otimes\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]$-modules for each $i$ such that the restriction to the intersection to the intersection of two open sets of the covering coincides

Comment: I agree with you @hm2020 that $s$ should be an automorphism. Nevertheless, we have arise to that conclusion because in the locally free case, $G$ is locally of the form $G=A$ (with your notation)

Comment: The above turned out to be wrong: There is a 1-1 correspondence between $A[\epsilon]$-automorphisms of $E[\epsilon]$ and $End_A(E)$ as claimed in the paper you are reading (see below). For this to hold you need $E$ to be torsion free. Any finite rank projective $A$-module $E$ is torsion free.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "Can anybody explain to me why this is true or at least give some reference for this (a priori, well-known) fact?"

**Answer:** Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $E$ a finite rank projective $A$-module and let $B:=A[\epsilon], E[\epsilon]:=A[\epsilon]\otimes_A E$. You may check that a $B$-linear endomorphism $\phi$ of $B\otimes_A E$ "inducing the identity" must be on the following form:

$$\phi(x+y\epsilon)=x+(s(x)+y)\epsilon.$$

Written in "matrix notation" you get

\begin{align*} \phi:= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ s & 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}

where $s\in End_A(E)$. The inverse $\phi^{-1}$ is given by the matrix

\begin{align*} \psi:=\phi^{-1}:= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -s & 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}

and you may check that $\phi \circ \psi = \psi \circ \phi=Identity$, hence $\phi$ and $\phi$ are automorphisms of the $B$-module $B\otimes_A E$. The element $s\in End_A(E)$ can be an arbitrary element, and this gives a 1-1 correspondence between automorphisms of the $B$-module $B\otimes_A E$ inducing the identity on $A\cong A[\epsilon]/(\epsilon)$ and the endomorphisms $End_A(E)$. You need $E$ to be a finite rank projective $A$-module for this to hold ($E$ must be torsion free) - the fact that $E$ is torsion free implies the above description of the matrices $\phi, \psi$. This "proves" the case of principal $GL_n$-bundles.

If $X$ is a scheme and $E$ is a locally trivial finite rank sheaf on $X$ you get for any $s\in End_{\mathcal{O}_X}(E)$ an endomorphism

$$\phi_s: E[\epsilon] \rightarrow E[\epsilon]$$

defined locally by (let $U \subseteq X$ be an open subscheme)

$$\phi_s(U)(x+y\epsilon):=x+(s_U(x)+y)\epsilon.$$

Here $s_U$ is the restriction of $s$ to $U$. This gives a 1-1 correspondence between the $\mathcal{O}_{X[\epsilon]}$-automorphisms of $E[\epsilon]$ inducing the identity on $X:=V(\epsilon) \subseteq X[\epsilon]$ and $End_{\mathcal{O}_X}(E)$. The result is in fact more general:

**Theorem** If $E$ is a torsion free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, there is a 1-1 correspondence between the set of $\mathcal{O}_{X[\epsilon]}$-automorphisms of $E[\epsilon]$ inducing the identity on $X \subseteq X[\epsilon]$ and $\mathcal{O}_X$-linear endomorphisms $\phi: E \rightarrow E$.

**Note:** If a more general principal fiber bundle $\pi:E \rightarrow X$ has sheaf of sections $sh(\pi)$ that is a finite rank locally trivial $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, I believe the same argument applies.